# AWS Glue Crawlers: Is it possible to infer changing column names and map them to a pre-defined column name in the data catalogue?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a requirement to load data repeatedly from CSV files, the data is to land in a output file/table with a pre-defined structure. However, the column names of input file in each iteration may change slightly.

For example, a column name will be 'Serial_Num' in first iteration and it may be present as 'Serial_Number' in the next iteration.

If I define a data catalogue table with the column name say 'Serial_Num', is it possible for me to code possible variations of this name and map them all to the already defined column 'Serial_Num'?

I understand that the column names may come up with a different variation each time and it may not follow a generic pattern. I am looking to define some patterns that may be expected logically, so that a manual intervention can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

In case every csv file is going to have first row as header, you can use following syntax on athena to create the required table in Glue Catalog :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {{tablename}} ({{headers}}) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'escapeChar'='/', 'quoteChar'='\\"', 'separatorChar'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
LOCATION '{{location}}' TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')"
```

Replace the place holders {{tablename}}, {{headers}} and {{location}} with respective values.

Even better solution would be to stop generating the header rows in the CSV itself, and then you can impose your own schema/headers on top of it with CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command in athena  or through Glue Crawler.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Harsh. But I see a problem with that, suppose the next iteration of csv file contains an extra column 'product_name'; in that case I will not be able to consume it at all if I start ignoring headers. Also, in some cases the order of headers may change across iterations (while the name remains the same). So I was hoping to define some kind of wild-card expressions to interpret the header names and map them to an existing column in the catalogue.

Comment: Basically, I want to run the crawler for every iteration and identify the new format, then align that to existing data catalogue. If its a new column, I want to add it to the target structure or ignore (depending on the need); while if its a re-ordered column or a simple header name change, I want it to be consumed as it was in the previous iteration... Is this even doable? :) Thanks

Comment: @user12109244, this is not possible through glue catalog. Whether thorugh crawler or through athena, you can not create a single table on top of files with different schema. Changing column names would not matter, if we are imposing our own headers. However, the column order and no of column must be same.

Comment: By creating a table on top of your data, you are actually marking it as a structured data, which will have a fixed schema.

Comment: Interesting... thank you very much for your time and insights on this. I will probably have to figure out a different strategy then; I was under the impression that Glue and Crawlers (classifier based control) can be useful.